# finding duplicate hash keys in perl and finding maximum value among them

Tags: perl, hash, key, duplicates

my data is in a file basically like :

```
a
2
b
6
a
4
f
2
b
1
a
7
```

I have this hash :

```
%hash = {
    a => 2,
    b => 6,
    a => 4,
    f => 2,
    b => 1, 
    a => 7,
};
```

How can I find duplicate keys and among them? I want the one that have the biggest value.

Desired output:

```
a-->7 
b-->6
f-->2
```

Comment: Hashes cannot have duplicate keys.

Comment: what is the best structure then

Comment: Depends on how/where you're getting your data. You can _use_ a hash to  keep counts/min/max/whatever of a dataset, but without knowing how you're getting your data, there's not telling how best to do that.

Comment: You could build the hash in such a way that you only set the value if its current value is lower.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you only ever want the highest value for a particular key, then add the logic into your assignment to the hash.  At the point you would add a key and a value, do something like this:

```
unless (exists $hash{$key} and $hash{$key} >= $value)
{
   $hash{$key} = $value;
}
```

If you need to preserve all values, then make each key point to an array of values.  Here is what your assignment would look like:

```
#Add an element to the array of values for this key.
push @{ $hash{$key} }, $value;
```

Here is a nice way to find the maximum value in the resultant array for a given key:

```
use List::Util qw/max/;

print max @{ $hash{$key} };
```

Answer (score 0):

So the task is to read the lines two by two. Using the first as key and the second as value you have to keep track of the largest value for each key.

```
%info;

# A loop reading two lines.
while( my $key = <> ) {
    my $value = <>;

    # Handle the case where there are an odd number of lines.
    die "Odd number of lines" unless (defined $value);

    # Assuming only non-negative values, we just silently want to compare
    # keys not seen before as having value 0. See 'perllexwarn' manual page
    no warnings 'uninitialized'; 

    $info{$key} = $value if $info{$key} <= $value;
}

# Dump the result
say "$_ --> $info{$_} for keys %info;
```

But as usual, there is more than one way to do it. Especially the reading of two lines at a time. Also some people might prefer to explicitly testing if `$info{$key}`already exists instead of just silencing the warning.

Comment: It is much better practice to actually check if `$info{$key}` exists.  Going down the route of `no warnings` is a slippery slope.  Sure, it is no big deal in this simple example, but as your code within the `while` loop gets more complex, you are opening yourself up to dumb mistakes.

Comment: @dan Actually, this will lead to a fatal flaw in the cases where the largest value is negative. Undef will be considered zero and corrupt that hash key.

Comment: @pmakholm :how can I check the existence of $info{$key}